# Moving a Formula from VBA Using ActiveCell.Formula for a Cell to Concatenate per specs

Tags: vba, excel

In trying to paste a formula through VBA into cell M2, I am not getting it to work and the error is not apparent. The formula in Excel is the following:

```
=IF(D2="",C2,IF(E2="",CONCATENATE(C2 &";"& D2),IF(F2="",CONCATENATE(C2&";"&D2&";"&E2),IF(G2="",CONCATENATE(C2&";"&D2&";"&E2&";"&F2),CONCATENATE(C2&";"&D2&";"&E2&";"&F2&";"&G2)))))
```

Within VBA I am trying to use the following:

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(D2="",C2,IF(E2="",CONCATENATE(C2" & "&""; """ &  "&D2"),IF(F2="",CONCATENATE(C2" & "&""; """ &  "&D2" & "&""; """ &  "&E2",IF(G2="",CONCATENATE(C2" & "&""; """ &  "&D2" & "&""; """ &  "&E2" & "&""; """ &  "&F2",CONCATENATE(C2" & "&""; """ &  "&D2" & "&""; """ &  "&E2" & "&""; """ &  "&F2" & "&""; """ &  "&G2"))
```

Even this does not work:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(D2="",C2,IF(E2="",CONCATENATE(C2 &"";""& D2),IF(F2="",CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2),IF(G2="",CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2&"";""&F2),CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2&"";""&F2&"";""&G2)))))"
```

The whole code is as follows:

```
Sub PutBackTogether()
'
' PutBackTogether Macro
'

'
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(D2="",C2,IF(E2="",CONCATENATE(C2 &"";""& D2),IF(2="",CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2),IF(G2="",CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2&"";""&F2),CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2&"";""&F2&"";""&G2)))))"
Range("M3").Select
Columns("M:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("M2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M147248")
Range("M2:M147248").Select
Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 17.29
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("D:M").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Can someone easily identify the context of my error(s)?

Comment: at the end, you are deleting columns `D:M` but your formulas are in column `M`

Comment: Correct, I just want to get the formula to work, then I can worry about the copying and pasting those values over into Column C. I have basically ticked out all of the bottom of the code. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot paste the string directly into VBA, the quotes around your `D2=""` are being parsed by VBA rather than being put into the formula.

You must double up on quotes for them to stay in the string, like so

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(D2="""",C2,IF(E2="""",CONCATENATE(C2 &"";""& D2),IF(F2="""",CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2),IF(G2="""",CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2&"";""&F2),CONCATENATE(C2&"";""&D2&"";""&E2&"";""&F2&"";""&G2)))))"
```

Consider using the range directly instead of selecting it first, if you want to continue building macros the select/active cell stuff will quickly bog you and excel down.

Instead of

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = ...
```

Try

```
Range("M2").Formula = ...
```

Works for everything else you have in there too

```
Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:= Range("M2:M147248")
```